# getting error in vb.net while we send mail to outlook using vb.net

Tags: sendmail, vb.net-2010, smtpclient

using vb.net to send mail to outlook. but am getting error like "the specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address" How to solve this problem
     Dim Var_from As String = TextBox1.Text
     Dim to_var As String = TextBox2.Text

```
    Dim mailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()


    mailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("'" + Var_from + "'")
    mailMessage.To.Add("'" + to_var + "'")
    mailMessage.Subject = "xxx"

    Dim content As String = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><style type='text/css'>#mytable { padding: 0;   margin: 0;border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;       border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;   border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;}caption {padding: 0 0 5px 0; width: 700px;font: Bold 11px 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;      text-align: right;}th {   font: bold 11px 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     color: #4f6b72;      border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;   letter-spacing: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left;       padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px; background: #CAE8EA; }td {  border-right: 0px solid #C1DAD7;  border-bottom: 0px solid #C1DAD7; border-left: 0px solid #C1DAD7;   background: #fff;    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;  color: #4f6b72;}</style></head><body><table border='0' cellpadding='0' id='mytable'  width='100%'><tr><th height='74' style='text-align:center; font-size:16px;' colspan='6'>CAS E-mail Confirmation <div style='float:right;'><img src='cid:HDIImage1' width='143' height='62' align='left' alt='' style='position:absolute;top:0pc;'/></div></th></tr><tr><td colspan='6' class='style5'>&nbsp;Dear Customer,<br/><br/> Thank you for  registering CAS. Click the below link to complete your verification process.. <br/><br/><br/>CAS CODE  :  <br/><br/><br/><br/></td></tr>  <tr>    <th colspan='6' class='style5'>&nbsp;</th>  </tr></table></body></html>"

    Dim plainTextView As System.Net.Mail.AlternateView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, Nothing, "text/plain")

    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainTextView)
    Dim smtpClient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

    smtpClient.Host = "xxx"
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use normal email addresses - the single quotes that you are adding might be causing the error. Do it without the extra quotes.

```
mailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Var_from)
mailMessage.To.Add(to_var)
```

Comment: What happens to the table with your current code? Is the email coming through as plain text instead of HTML? Try adding `mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True`

Comment: am creating the table with one row how to set this html code in mail content